# multiple markers on google maps from xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am so close to get this working

**My question is: how can i make the google maps read the data.xml file that is stored on my ftp server?**

The xml file look like this:

```
<markers>
<marker>
    <lat>57.709</lat>
    <lng>11.9799</lng>
    </marker>
<marker>
    <lat>57.6468</lat>
    <lng>11.9961</lng>
    </marker>
</markers>
```

This is the code for the map:

```
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.4419, 11.1419);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  downloadUrl("data.xml", function(data) {
    var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                  parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

This is the PHP code for the XML file:

```
$xml="<markers>\n\t\t"; 
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $xml .="<marker>\n\t\t";
    $xml .= "<lat>".$data['latitude']."</lat>\n\t\t";
    $xml .= "<lng>".$data['longitude']."</lng>\n\t\t";
    $xml .="</marker>\n\t";
}
$xml.="</markers>\n\r";
$handle = fopen('data.xml', 'w') or die('Cannot open data.xml');
fwrite($handle, $xml);
```

It's saved as data.xml and my maps should load that but no markers show up.

Appreciate any response to this.

Comment: lat & lng are not attributes of the `<marker>` element.

Comment: oh, so what is the attributes of the <marker> element?

Comment: Your xml doesn't have any. `<marker lat="xx.xx" lng="xx.xx"></marker>` would be attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three standard formats for "mapping" XML (XML stands for [eXtensible Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), you can do with it what you want).

- [KML](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference?csw=1) - content of a `<coordinates>` element, multiple values are possible separated by strings.

```
<Placemark>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>go 0.3&amp;#160;mi</description>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-103.17619,44.09972,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

[example parser - geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

- latitude/longitude attributes of a marker element (used in and described in [Mike Williams' Google Maps Javascript API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic3.htm))

```
<marker lat="44.09972" lng="-103.17619" />
```

Parse using code like you have posted in your question:

```
var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
 }
```

- latitude/longitude content in separate elements

```
<marker>
  <latitude>44.09972</latitude>
  <longitude>-103.17619</longitude>
</marker>
```

Parse by getting the *content* of the `<latitude>` and `<longitude>` elements:

```
var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementByTagName("latitude")[0])),
                                      parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementByTagName("longitude")[0])));
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map});
}
```

from [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js):

```
//nodeValue: Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed
function nodeValue (node) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return '';
  }
  if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
    retStr+=node.nodeValue;
  } else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
    for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
      retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return retStr;
};
```

[question on SO about how to do this using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337368/loading-markers-from-xml-file-to-google-map-api) - [example from that question](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_readXmlElements.html)

xml format parsed:

```
<marker>
  <lat>44.09972</lat>
  <lng>-103.17619</lng>
</marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latitude and longitude is stored as content of  the lat/lng-childNodes of the marker's

You may access the values via:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i]
                                                .getElementsByTagName("lat")[0]
                                                  .firstChild.nodeValue),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i]
                                                .getElementsByTagName("lng")[0]
                                                  .firstChild.nodeValue));
```