# How to display in google maps based on our latitude and longitude in xml format

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have created a web service to return latitude and longitude in XML format as attached below:

```
<geocode>
<latitude>46.22764</latitude>
<longitude>2.213749</longitude>
</geocode>
```

Is it possible to use this xml format value of latitude and longitude to map and display on Google Maps using javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What does your existing code look like?  What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: [related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997077/multiple-markers-on-google-maps-from-xml-file/21011311#21011311)

Answer (score 0):

try this in iframe. create URL dynamically using javascript

https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/46.2276+2.213749/@46.22764,2.213749